# How can I overwrite the btnSubmit_onclick javascript function on a web page using the WPF WebBrowser?

Tags: javascript, wpf, browser, mshtml, overwrite

I'm working with the WPF `WebBrowser` control which is different from the WinForms version and many recommendations from this excellent web site simply do not work in WPF.

How can I overwrite the `btnSubmit_onclick()` javascript function on a web page?

This function generates a confirm dialog (like "Are you sure?") which I want to bypass. Basically I want to inject a new function `btnSubmit_onclick()` which will replace the existing one and I can omit annoying confirm dialog. I have access to MSHTML and all page objects, but struggle to inject script at the header of the page. So far I've got:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document;
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection heads = doc.all.tags("head") as mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection;
mshtml.IHTMLElement head = heads.item(null, 0) as mshtml.IHTMLElement;
mshtml.IHTMLElement se = doc.createElement("script") as mshtml.IHTMLElement;
se.innerHTML = "function btnSubmit_onclick() { alert('here we are'); }";
```

But now I need to inject this new script element into head object before other the other scripts, and I hope it will owerwrite existing `btnSubmit_onclick()` function downstream.

I unsuccessfully tried head.injectAdjusentHTML which refuses to inject any script into the header even I use DEFER property.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add it to the end of the head instead of inject it before the others. I believe javascript is a last-one-wins type of deal.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested this, is just a guess:
Try this:

```
// For this code to work: add the Microsoft.mshtml .NET reference
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WebBrowser1.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.parentWindow.execScript("document.body.onsubmit=new function(){ alert('here we are'); };");
```