# How to inject <DIV> into WPF WebBrowser Control  to  overlap  all webpage content within?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

What I want to do is when WPF WebBrowser loads page I just want to put over page content some  **to prevent any click events** from user within downloaded page.

So the idea is somehow insert that  including it style into downloaded page...

Is it possible to do?

If yes, then how it could be implemented in C#?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in WPF? I would try wrapping the control in a grid with a clear rectangle over the WebBrowser handling click events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you navigate to a `javascript:` URL?  That's probably the cheap way to do it, and I believe that's what I ended up doing in the past.

There's another way involving directly accessing the DOM.  It involves accessing `WebBrowser.Document`, which you can cast to a COM type.  I'll need to get back to you on the exact technique--I have it saved somewhere--but there's a tiny bit of a hint on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document.aspx).

Edit:

The easiest way to test the JavaScript would be to do something like:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:alert('Test');")
```

If you get a dialog saying `Test` without your web page disappearing, it works.  You can insert any JavaScript you want there, provided the test worked.  For example:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.body.innerHTML = '<div>Test</div>' + document.body.innerHTML);");
```

### The Proper Way

I'm going to give this a shot, but it's untested, so keep in mind that you might need to tweak this process a bit.

1. Reference to `ShDocVw.dll`.
2. Add a `using` statement for the `mshtml` namespace.
3. Cast the `WebBrowser.Document` object to an `mshtml.IHTMLDocument2` interface.
4. This should give you access to the document's DOM, so you should be able to use IntelliSense to figure out what to do from here.  You'll be using COM, though, so it will be a bit of a pain, and will require a lot of work with interfaces.

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592688/how-can-i-overwrite-the-btnsubmit-onclick-javascript-function-on-a-web-page-usin) has some good examples.  I would use plain casting instead of the `as` keyword, though.  `obj as Something` is syntax sugar for `obj is Something ? (Something)obj : null`.  That extra test really is unnecessary here.

Comment: I updated my answer with the "proper" technique.  I only ever recall using this once, because it is such a pain and relies on a DLL that is prone to misplacement.  There isn't too much documentation on it, but I did find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592688/how-can-i-overwrite-the-btnsubmit-onclick-javascript-function-on-a-web-page-usin).

Comment: I really appreciate your help, bro!